# In Django, how do I remove a permission from my site?

Tags: django

I added a permission to a model using the way recommended in the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/options/#permissions). E.g.

```
class Car(Model):
    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ('can_drive', 'User is allowed to drive this car'),
        )
```

I then decided I don't want that permission so I removed the `class Meta...` code and ran:

```
./manage.py makemigrations
./manage.py migrate
```

`./manage.py` told me it removed the `class Meta...` code but the permission is still in Django admin.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the permission manually using the Django shell

```
./manage.py shell

from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
Permission.objects.filter(codename='can_drive').delete()
```